# "Awaiting Reviewer Invitation" after "Acceptance with Minor Revision"

Tags: publications

I have submitted an article (media and communication studies) to a ScholarOne journal. The paper was accepted with minor revision (two reviewers both recommended 'minor revision'). I revised the paper accordingly and addressed the feedbacks. After submitting the revised article for a week, a ADM was assigned and the status has changed to "awaiting reviewer invitation." Does it mean that my paper will go through another round of review with new reviewers? I was told that for paper with "minor revision," it is likely like it will not be sent back to the reviewers. Has anyone experienced similar situation?

Comment: It is completely normal for papers with minor revisions to go through more than one round of revisions. If the editors deem ir necessary and the reviewers that volunteered for the first round of the review are unavailable, they might need to invite new ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it mean your paper will go through another round of review? Not necessarily. It depends on whether the editor invites new reviewers. "Awaiting reviewer invitation" should strictly be a very brief status, since the time between the editor deciding to invite reviewers and the editor actually inviting reviewers should be very brief, on the order of a few minutes. The fact that you are apparently seeing this status for more than a brief moment indicates that the journal is using it as a substitute for "Editor assigned".

You can think about the timeline as so:

- Your paper is resubmitted. Status shows "Revision submitted to journal".
- Either the desk editor (i.e. the employee of the publisher assigned to the journal) or the editor-in-chief assigns an editorial board member to handle the paper. Here the status could show "Editor assigned", or it could show "awaiting reviewer invitation".
- The editorial board member could make a decision now, or they could go ahead and invite reviewers. It depends on how substantial the changes requested are, and whether the editor is able to check it himself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what "awaiting reviewer invitation" means.

But usually, the paper with minor revision will be sent directly back to the same reviewers for the final decision. They need to check whether you revise according to their reviews.